# Integrate Boolean Operators in SearchBox in a React/ElasticSearch/Django website

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, search, searchkit, boolean-search

I am creating a website using django and React. I have setup a search engine using elasticsearch and I showed the data in my website using React-searchkit. I want to integrate boolean search in my searchbox to allow the user to search using boolean operators like this:
[image]

so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can to start in [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(new york city) OR (big apple)",
      "default_field": "content"
    }
  }
}
```